# How to highlight entire TextBox on triple click?

Tags: c#, winforms

When there are spaces between the text in the Input TextBox, my triple click only highlights up to the next space instead of the whole TextBox. Help?

Comment: That's normal behavior. It happens everywhere, and it's what users will expect. Edit your question here, put in two or three words, and then double-click on one of them, and you'll see that only that word and the space that follows it will be selected.

Comment: How about triple-clicking?

Comment: @KenWhite Notepad uses triple clicks to select whole lines of text

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the DoubleClick event:

```
private void textBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;  // set the selection start index to the beginning
    textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;  // set the selection length to the length of the text
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: How about a triple click?